# How to distinguish delimiter for different states in scanner-generator?

Tags: c#, lexical-analysis, dfa

I have implemented a simple Scanner-Generator.

I am experiencing one problem during making, it's about the delimiter classification.

For example, if a white-space is included, such as "a + b", you can create an id+plus+id tokens by simply delimiter the white-space. However, if there is no white-space like "a+b", it is treated as an unrecognized rule, not id+plus+id.

If specify a delimiter every time, this is a problem to be solved, but in the case of "023abc" it was interpreted as number+id and could not be easily applied.

Let me know if there is a way to handle this problem.

My Code: https://github.com/rollrat/compiler-compiler

Comment: Generally, you will want your tokenizer to be able to handle the differences, and you define a specification of your language to make it clear how tokens will be interpreted. If you want `023abc` to be interpreted as number+id, then make it clear in your specification. While you're tokenizing your inputs, you get to define whatever behaviour you want. If you want to allow `a+b` without a delimiter, then your lexer will have to not be based on delimiters.

Comment: @Welbog I was thinking and making completely different from the original Lex. That was my terrible mistakes. Very very helpful. Thank you!